# Adding SMT/HyperThreading to a Verilog design?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am wondering how it SMT/HyperThreading being added to a Verilog HDL design?

The planned design(something similar):
http://www.fpga4student.com/2017/01/verilog-code-for-single-cycle-MIPS-processor.html

I am wondering, is there any special kind of syntax to add the SMT function, and if so, where?

I haven't tried anything so far, because I don't know where to start and google doesn't help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not just adding Hyper-Threading "functions". You design your cpu in a way that allows simultaneous execution of multiple instructions on multiple/independent execution units. Typically that means pipelined design, which is not the case for single-cycle processor.

For processors as simple as that single-cycle, it's easier to instantiate multiple CPUs (SMP) and design a way to share resources (memory, peripherals, etc).

Comment: Thanks, but regardles of single cycle CPU, when i need that feature for a more copmlex CPU, how do i share multiple instructions on multiple independent execution units? Any high level overview so i can better imagine?

Comment: You need pipeline for that. Something that gets filled with many instructions to be executed, then selecting which of execution units is free to perform some stages of instructions, then schedule specific instruction's stages to those free units, and that way you have multiple instructions executed simultaneously. You can't do all that in a single cycle on a scalar cpu. Wikipedia has an overview for Intel's approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Comment: Ok. I got it now. Can you link any example design in verilog, so i can see how it is being done?